# how to change language in django-ckeditor-5

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, ckeditor5, django-ckeditor

hello I'm working on a django project.

I want to change language of  django-ckeditor-5 How should I do this?

and is django-ckeditor-5 package same as django-ckeditor package ?